# Usar diferentes archivos strings.xml independientemente del Locale

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

Me gustaría saber si, sin cambiar el `Locale` de la app, hay alguna posibilidad de elegir qué archivo de `strings.xml` usar en la app.

Por ejemplo, si tengo un archivo de `strings.xml` y al traducir este he creado uno nuevo `strings.xml(en)`, hacer que, si yo así lo quiero, cuando el Locale sea es_ES use el segundo archivo, es decir, el de string.xml(en).

¿Es posible hacer esto? Si no lo es ¿Valdría con cambiar el Locale para que use un recurso u otro?

Por lo que he leído, se supone que sí. No obstante, yo lo he hecho y no funciona.

**Código:**

```
 Locale aLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("en").setRegion("US").build();
                    Locale.setDefault(aLocale);
                    getResources().getConfiguration().setLocale(aLocale);

 Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault().getCountry()+Locale.getDefault().getLanguage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //muestra USen
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//muestra English
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),current.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//muestra en_US
```

A pesar de dichos resultados, el texto no varía.

Comment: ¿@pepito has probado el código que te puse?

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estás teniendo sino me equivoco es que no se te está guardando la configuración del idioma elegida por lo que no está cogiendo bien los strings.

Para ello prueba a guardar la configuración de la siguiente forma:

```
String language = "en";

Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
Locale sysLocale = null;

//obtenemos la configuración del idioma actual
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    sysLocale = getSystemLocale(config);
} else {
    sysLocale = getSystemLocaleLegacy(config);
}

//comprobamos si la configuración actual del idioma es distinta a la que queremos cambiar.
if (!language.equals("") && !sysLocale.getLanguage().equals(language)) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    //Actualizamos el locale
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
           setSystemLocale(config, locale);
    } else {
           setSystemLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
    }

    //Actualizamos la configuración
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
           context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
    } else {
          context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

Este código está preparado para versiones recientes y anteriores de Android, puedes echarle un vistazo a esta [publicación](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40704077/3683321) de SO en el que indica cómo hacerlo y te explica cómo hacer un `wrapper` para no tener que estar cambiando la configuración en cada actividad.

Sino quieres utilizar un Wrapper se podría hacer el cambio de idioma dentro de una clase que extienda de Application y definir ahí la configuración del idioma, para no estar cambiándolo en todas las actividades.

Creo que con esto podrás solventar tu problema.

Comment: ¿@pepito has probado el código que te puse?